# Using custom build configuration in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, buildconfiguration

In my client application I sometimes connect to  `localhost:1242\SomeService.asmx` and some other times it connects to `someDomain:1242\SomeService.asmx`. In other words there are times when I want to test locally and some other times remotely.

The default options that VS gives you are debug and release. I want to create custom ones in fact I have just created a new build configuration:
[image]

Anyhow how can I know in code if I am using that configuration?

I will like to do something like:

```
if(Configuration.Type == ConfigTypes.Local)
    ConectionString = "localhost:1242:\SomeService.asmx";
else if (Configuration.Type == ConfigTypes.Remote1)
    ConectionString = "SomeDomain1:1242:\SomeService.asmx";
else if (Configuration.Type == ConfigTypes.Remote2)
    ConectionString = "SomeDifDomain:1242:\SomeService.asmx";
```

Also release mode tends to be more efficient? How will I specify those settings?

Comment: can you use config transforms and an app.config file?

Comment: Can you use different conditional compilation constants?

Comment: Never tried. Yes I can. I am just curios on how to make this work because it will be very easy and convenient to change configurations by just changing a drop down instead of having to go to the app.config file.

Comment: yes its a build time process. theres plenty of resources on them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define conditional compilation symbols.
*Project properties → Build tab → Conditional compilation symbols*.
Define there different symbols for different configurations, for instance:

- `SRV_LOCAL` in the "Local" configuration;
- `SRV_REMOTE1` in the "Remote1" configuration;
- `SRV_REMOTE2` in the "Remote2" configuration.

Then in the code:

```
#if SRV_LOCAL
    private const string SERVER = "localhost";
#elseif SRV_REMOTE1
    private const string SERVER = "SomeDomain1";
#elseif SRV_REMOTE2
    private const string SERVER = "SomeDifDomain";
#endif
```

Comment: Plus one thanks for the help! thats a solution I am just curios to see if the other option works. If its not possible I will accept this answer.